# Using spring security plugin with alternative database schema

Tags: grails, plugins, spring-security, schema

i want to use spring security and to map my model to a simplistic database schema.
According to this: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#db_schema_users_authorities (section user schema), i can have a that match the one i have.

Note that this schema is the basic schema of tomcat with the database realm.

But i don't know how to tell spring to which schema i use and what are the tables to use wich what fields.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the Grails Spring Security plugin you're lookingin the wrong place - you don't configure it using standard Spring Security but within the plugin itself.

This is a common enough customization that it has its own chapter in the plugin docs - see https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/userDetailsService.html

Comment: thanks for pointing me this page. I was looking for something simpler.
Since my app doesn't require such sofistication (as spring security offerd), I decided to get rid of it. And use a simple container managed security.